# Extend enum and use it in overridden method in java

Tags: java, inheritance, enums, jackson, jackson-modules

I am facing an issue regarding extending a method from abstract which returns enum.

Below abstract class from com.fasterxml.jackson library which I need to extend.

```
public abstract class JsonSchema
{
    public abstract JsonFormatTypes getType();
}
```

And JsonFormatTypes is enum:

```
public enum JsonFormatTypes
{
    STRING,
    NUMBER,
    INTEGER,
    BOOLEAN,
    OBJECT,
    ARRAY,
    NULL,
    ANY;
}
```

Now I want extend JsonSchema clas for SwitchSchema and JsonFormatTypes to Have Type as "SWITCH"

```
public class SwitchSchema extends JsonSchema
{
    @Override
    public JsonFormatTypes getType(){
        return JsonFormatTypes.SWITCH;
    }
}
```

Now my question is how to extend JsonFormatTypes enum to have "SWITCH" and use it in overridden method ?

Comment: you can't extend an enum, but you can extend classes. why don't you convert your enum to a class?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot extend an `enum`.

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html):

> All enums implicitly extend `java.lang.Enum`. Because a class can only extend one parent (see [Declaring Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classdecl.html)), the Java language does not support multiple inheritance of state (see [Multiple Inheritance of State, Implementation, and Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/multipleinheritance.html)), and therefore an enum cannot extend anything else.

Despite some online literature (e.g. [here](https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/wiki/switch-%28v5-proposal%29)), the `switch` statement is not currently supported by JSON, hence `JsonFormatTypes` (from [Jackson](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsonFormatVisitors/JsonFormatTypes.html), I suppose) is fine as is, and you probably don't want to use it any differently.

If you're trying to make a new specification for the JSON format, you might be better off using your own parser instead of relying on a third-party.